# Is the stripe transaction attribute data-name automatically included in the payload of stripe webhooks?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, webhooks

I need to identify some meta data associated with a stripe transaction and it seems the easiest way to do this is to encode it into the `data-name` attribute that is used when setting up the stripe payment button with javascript.

Is the `data-name` attribute automatically included the payload sent by stripe webhooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe Checkout only creates card tokens from the card details entered by the Customer. It won't store any of the parameters you passed to configure Checkout as those are for display only.

The real amount you charge is when you call the Create Charge [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) server-side after creating the token. At that point, you can set any [Metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api#metadata) you want which would be sent along with the `charge.*` events after creation.

Comment: So assuming I set the necessary metadata in the charge.* call, at that point this data will be included with all webhooks correct?

Comment: Sweet - Thanks @koopajah!